# Virtual functions that act like dynamic casts

Tags: c++, rtti

In [JOINT STRIKE FIGHTER AIR VEHICLE C++ CODING STANDARDS](https://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf)  Bjarne states, that:

> Down casting (casting from base to derived class) shall only be
> allowed through one of the following mechanism:
>
> 1. Virtual functions that act like dynamic casts (most likely useful in
>    relatively simple cases)
> 2. Use of the visitor (or similar) pattern (most likely useful in
>    complicated cases)

I can't wrap my head around first proposition. Googling it presented no examples, nor explanation.

**How can virtual function act like a dynamic cast?**

Comment: A virtual function exposes functionality that exists in a more derived class.  As does dynamic downcasting.

Comment: I'm guessing it's saying that a virtual function in a derived class will always receive a `this` pointer of the derived type, not the parent type. It may also mean that because of the previous behaviour you can write virtual functions to perform downcasting without having to use a slow `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: A virtual function dispatches from the base class to the correct derived class member function.  A dynamic cast and manually calling the function does the same thing, hence a virtual function call is like an implicit dynamic cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's referring to a technique that was kind of common in the early days of C++, before `dynamic_cast`, `RTTI`, etc., were added to the language.

The basic idea looks something like this:

```cpp
class Derived1;
class Derived2;

class Base {
public:
    virtual Derived1 *toDerived1() const { return nullptr; }
    virtual Derived2 *toDerivde2() const { return nullptr; }
};

class Derived1 : public Base { 
public:
    Derived1 *toDerived1() const override { return this; }
    Derived2 *toDerived2() const override { return nullptr; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base { 
public:
    Derived1 *toDerived1() const override { return nullptr; }
    Derived2 *toDerived2() const overrode { return this; }
};
```

This lets you do something just about like a `dynamic_cast` on a pointer, yielding a pointer to the expected type if the pointee object is actually of that type, and otherwise a `nullptr`.

This has obvious disadvantages though. Every class involved has to be aware of every other class. Adding a new class means adding a new function to every class. Unless the entire class structure is quite static (and a small number of classes altogether), this can quickly turn into a maintenance nightmare.

**Reference**

This technique was covered in Effective C++, 1st Edition, Item 39. I haven't checked to be sure, but it was probably dropped from the newer editions, as (at least in the minds of most programmers) the addition of `dynamic_cast` rendered it obsolescent (at best).

Comment: Ehm, haven't you forgotten something in the code? Like Inheritance?

Comment: @MatG: oops. Yes, I obviously did.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a virtual function to downcast like this:

```
struct Bar;

struct Foo {
  virtual Bar* as_bar() { return nullptr; }
};

struct Bar : Foo {
  Bar* as_bar() override { return this; }
};
```

Not often used, in practice.

Comment: Oh! I had a question that why in books say: asNode() is better than using dynamic_cast<Node*>() , you answered me by this example , Thanks!